# Como pegar o "style" de um elemento dentro de uma div

Tags: javascript, html

Queria pegar o tamanho da letra do elemento com o id "teste"

```
<div id="div">
    <h1 id="teste">OLÁ</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível saber o tamanho da letra através de Javascript:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("teste")).fontSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) para obter todos os estilos do elemento `h1`, e em seguida o `font-size`:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('teste');
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(h1, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
console.log("font-size: " + fontSize);
```

```html
<div id="div">
    <h1 id="teste">OLÁ</div>
</div>
```